# Please how to solve this one using oauth2.0

Tags: iphone, oauth-2.0

Please how to solve this issue... link mismatch

I'm trying to use OAUTH2.0 in my apps...
When i try to install to physical phone.. i got below message.
But when i tried on simulator is everything ok.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
>   "_kGTMHTTPFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
>         -[GTMOAuth2Authentication beginTokenFetchWithDelegate:didFinishSelector:] in
>   libOAuthTouch2.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>         -[GTMOAuth2SignIn authCodeObtained] in libOAuthTouch2.a(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMHTTPFetcher",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libOAuthTouch2.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>         objc-class-ref in libOAuthTouch2.a(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)   "_GTMAssertSelectorNilOrImplementedWithArgs", referenced from:
>         -[GTMOAuth2Authentication authorizeRequest:delegate:didFinishSelector:] in
>   libOAuthTouch2.a(GTMOAuth2Authentication.o)
>         -[GTMOAuth2SignIn initWithAuthentication:authorizationURL:delegate:webRequestSelector:finishedSelector:]
>   in libOAuthTouch2.a(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture armv7s clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Thanks

[image: Please how to solve this one]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to project ->build setting -> architecture and add armv6,armv7.

remove armv7s.  Similarly for the target->build setting->architecture.

armv define family of instruction set being used.

Comment: i am also getting the same problem but setting as in answer does not solve my problem. its xcode 7.3.1. Can you please help.

Comment: Its an old answer as you see will try to replicate and solve it.Mean while you can try to play with armvs available